# I am doing a query in SQL for calculating price for same category but I am getting duplicate values as I ran the query in my database

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

My query looks like

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderProduct.id AS [get_id],Category.id AS 

[get_cat_id],OrderProduct.actual_rate AS [get_price],OrderProduct.qty AS [qt],ProductType.slug as [pro_type],Orders.id AS [order_id]
FROM order_product OrderProduct 
LEFT JOIN orders Orders ON OrderProduct.order_id=Orders.id 
INNER JOIN products Products ON OrderProduct.product_id=Products.id 
INNER JOIN product_type ProductType ON (ProductType.id=Products.product_type_id AND ProductType.is_deleted = 'n')
LEFT JOIN category Category ON (Category.id=Products.category1_id OR Category.id=Products.category2_id) 
LEFT JOIN payment_methods PaymentMethods ON PaymentMethods.id=Orders.payment_method_id 
WHERE (Products.is_deleted = 'n' AND ProductType.slug = 'book' AND Orders.order_status not in ('payment_pending') AND Products.target_market_country_code = 'ko');
```

**My result is showing**
Here is my Result after running the query-

```
get_id  get_cat_id      get_price   qty pro_type   order_id
7       2               12000.00    2   book        8
35      2               1000.00     4   book        33
37      2               1000.00     1   book        35
50      2               12500.00    3   book        45
50      3               12500.00    3   book        45
52      2               25000.00    1   book        47
79      3               15200.00    1   book        74
79      28              15200.00    1   book        74
88      2               1000.00     2   book        83
89      2               1000.00     1   book        84
91      148             900.00      3   book        86
111     2               1000.00     5   book        106
130     3               300.00      1   book        125
```

there is 50 and 79 is duplicate
I want my result like that-

```
get_id  get_cat_id      get_price   qty pro_type   order_id
7       2               12000.00    2   book        8
35      2               1000.00     4   book        33
37      2               1000.00     1   book        35
50      2               12500.00    3   book        45
52      2               25000.00    1   book        47
79      3               15200.00    1   book        74
88      2               1000.00     2   book        83
89      2               1000.00     1   book        84
91      148             900.00      3   book        86
111     2               1000.00     5   book        106
130     3               300.00      1   book        125
```

In cakephp my query is looks like in controller

```
    $getQuery = $this->OrderProduct->find('all',['contain' => ['Orders' => ['PaymentMethods'],'Products' => ['ProductType','Category']]])->distinct('MAX(OrderProduct.id)')
                ->select([
                    'product_name' => 'MAX(Category.id)',
                    'count' => 'SUM(OrderProduct.qty)', 
                    'actual_rate' => 'SUM(OrderProduct.actual_rate)',
                    'revenue_based_actual_rate' => '(
                        SUM(
                            CASE
                            WHEN PaymentMethods.payment_gateway = \'nicepay\'
                            THEN (OrderProduct.actual_rate-((OrderProduct.actual_rate * :nicepayCommission)/100))
                            WHEN PaymentMethods.payment_gateway = \'paypal\'
                            THEN (OrderProduct.actual_rate-((OrderProduct.actual_rate * :paypalCommission)/100))
                            ELSE (OrderProduct.actual_rate)
                            END
                        )
                    )'
                ])
                ->bind(':nicepayCommission', $nicepay_commission, 'integer')
                ->bind(':paypalCommission', $paypal_commission, 'integer')->where($conditions);

                $getQuery->where(['Products.is_deleted' => 'n']); 

                $getQuery->where(['ProductType.slug' => $searchparams['product_type_id']]);

                $getQuery->where(['Orders.order_status NOT IN' => ['payment_pending']]);

                $getQuery->where(['Products.target_market_country_code' => $tcid]);

                $getAll = $getQuery->group('Category.id');
```

How can I remove duplicate values and get the perfect price.If I take the Category.id then its getting duplicate value but I need the category id.

Comment: When you have used Distinct there is no possibility of getting duplicate combination of Product.id and Category.id, could you please paste you result and expected result in the question(edit you question)

Comment: Edir your original question and paste the data in proper format.

Comment: I have added my result data please help me to fix it.

Comment: row with ID 50 is duplicate because both rows have different get_cat_id i.e. 2 and 3. You want 1 row per record and want to select row with lowest get_cat_id. You need to use row_number here.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like below:

First you will assign row_number within each get_id ordering by    get_cat_id and then you will select only row_number = 1

```
select a.* from (
SELECT  OrderProduct.id AS [get_id],Category.id AS 
[get_cat_id],OrderProduct.actual_rate AS [get_price],OrderProduct.qty AS [qt],ProductType.slug as [pro_type],Orders.id AS [order_id],
row_number() over(partition by OrderProduct.id order by Category.id) rn
FROM order_product OrderProduct 
LEFT JOIN orders Orders ON OrderProduct.order_id=Orders.id 
INNER JOIN products Products ON OrderProduct.product_id=Products.id 
INNER JOIN product_type ProductType ON (ProductType.id=Products.product_type_id AND ProductType.is_deleted = 'n')
LEFT JOIN category Category ON (Category.id=Products.category1_id OR Category.id=Products.category2_id) 
LEFT JOIN payment_methods PaymentMethods ON PaymentMethods.id=Orders.payment_method_id 
WHERE (Products.is_deleted = 'n' AND ProductType.slug = 'book' AND Orders.order_status not in ('payment_pending') AND Products.target_market_country_code = 'ko'))
a where rn = 1;
```